# C program displays garbage value while taking user input using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, function

I was writing a C program to find inversions in an array. The program compiles smoothly but as soon as I run it, it displays a garbage value where I take the array as a input. The program is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checkInversions(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j, inverse_count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                inverse_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return inverse_count;
}

int main() {
    int arr[10], i, n;

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: %d");

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);   
    }

    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);   

    printf("\n The inverse is: %d", checkInversions(arr, n));

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when the statement `Enter the elements of the array:` is displayed, just beside that is a garbage value like `623089`. I am able to take the input but the result is not correct. What is the cause of this? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=10;i++)` let count 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 that give... 11 what is your array size ?

Comment: You're also not checking the return value for `scanf()`.  You really don't know what's getting put into your array, so you don't know what the output should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `printf` with a format specifier for `%d` and nothing passed to satisfy the variable expected by the format string. This is undefined behavior.

What you meant to do was merely:

`printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");`

Also, since `arr` has 10 elements, you iterate through it as such:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

You don't need to use `sizeof` to determine the size of the array since you already know it; it's `10`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the variable that should populate the `%d` on the `printf`.
Try taking out the `%d` on the `printf` call so it ends up like:

```
printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");
```

Or assign the corresponding variable to display with that `"%d"`, like this:

```
printf("Enter the elements of the array: %d", variable);
```

Check if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `printf("Enter the elements of the array: %d");`. You tell the program that you want to print an integer, but you do not specify which integer that is. Remove the `%d` and the garbage value will be gone, like this: `printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");`